# Resizing a 48bit PNG retaining its 48bits, without dropping it to a 24bit file

Tags: python

I'm trying to resize the following  48bit PNG from 1242 x 375 to 256 x 256
but retain its 48 bits.

This PNG Ground Truth Image is available for [download here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3qfihrfsf2l2ddd/000000_10.png?dl=0)

I was wondering if there is a way to code it so that the 48bits is retained ?

I have tried a few different libraries, however the resultant file becomes a 24bit PNG.

```
# Resize 48bit PNG file and maintain 48bit PNG when saving to file

from PIL import Image
from numpngw import write_png
import cv2
import scipy
import imageio
import skimage

PNG_Location_Filepath = "..\\..\\000000_10.png"
out = "output_images\\"
#The Pillow way
im = Image.open(PNG_Location_Filepath)
PIL_imResized = im.resize((256,256), Image.ANTIALIAS)
libraryname = "Pillow"
savedfilename = out + libraryname + '.png'
PIL_imResized.save(savedfilename)

#The numpngw way
im = cv2.imread(PNG_Location_Filepath, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
cv2_imResized = cv2.resize(im, (256,256), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
libraryname = "numpngw"
savedfilename = out + libraryname + '.png'
write_png(savedfilename, cv2_imResized)

#The Scipy way / ImageIOSkimage way
#im = scipy.misc.imread(PNG_Location_Filepath,mode='RGB')
im = imageio.imread(PNG_Location_Filepath)
#Scipy_imResized = scipy.misc.imresize(im, [256, 256])
Skimage_imResized = skimage.transform.resize(im, (256, 256))
libraryname = "ImageIoSkimage"
savedfilename = out + libraryname + '.png'
#scipy.misc.imsave(savedfilename, Scipy_imResized)
imageio.imwrite(savedfilename, Skimage_imResized)

# `imread` is deprecated in SciPy 1.0.0, and will be removed in 1.2.0.
# Use ``imageio.imread`` instead
# `imresize` is deprecated in SciPy 1.0.0, and will be removed in 1.2.0.
# Use ``skimage.transform.resize`` instead
# `imsave` is deprecated in SciPy 1.0.0, and will be removed in 1.2.0
# Use ``imageio.imwrite`` instead.
```

I also tried this code, but received an error message

```
import cv2
import imageio
imageio.plugins.freeimage.download()
PNG_Location_Filepath = "..\\..\\000000_10.png"
Resized_Location_Filepath = "..\\..\\000000_10_resized.png"

imageio.plugins.freeimage.FreeimagePngFormat.Reader._open
(PNG_Location_Filepath)
img_in_imageio = imageio.imread(PNG_Location_Filepath, format='PNG-FI')
Resized_Image = cv2.resize(img_in_imageio, (256,256))
Saved_Filename = Resized_Location_Filepath
imageio.imwrite(Saved_Filename, Resized_Image, format='PNG-FI')
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  File "c:\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.6.24221\pythonFiles\ptvsd_launcher.py", line 43, in <module>    main(ptvsdArgs)  File "c:\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.6.24221\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\__main__.py", line 434, in main
    run()
  File "c:\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.6.24221\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\__main__.py", line 312, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target, run_name='__main__')
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Documents\DeepLearning\Learning\Code\Sandpit\Resize48bitKeeping48bit.py", line 10, in <module>
    img_in_imageio = imageio.plugins.freeimage.FreeimagePngFormat.Reader._open(PNG_Location_Filepath)
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\freeimage.py", line 221, in _open
    return FreeimageFormat.Reader._open(self, flags)
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\imageio\plugins\freeimage.py", line 81, in _open
    self._bm = fi.create_bitmap(self.request.filename, self.format.fif, flags)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'request'
```

So I tried this code

```
import cv2
import imageio
imageio.plugins.freeimage.download()
PNG_Location_Filepath = "..\\..\\000000_10.png"
Resized_Location_Filepath = "..\\..\\000000_10_resized.png"
img_in_imageio = imageio.imread(PNG_Location_Filepath, format='PNG-FI')
#img_in_imageio.resize((256,256,3))
Resized_Image = cv2.resize(img_in_imageio, (256,256))
Saved_Filename = Resized_Location_Filepath
imageio.imwrite(Saved_Filename, img_in_imageio, format='PNG-FI')
```

And this copied the file, but it didn't resize it

I am expecting the file format at uint48 to be maintained, however the output file seems to be 24bits

Comment: in imageio issuse you can see how to use it with FreeImage plugin to create even 64bit png (RGBA). [Unable to properly read multi-channel 16-bit png files](https://github.com/imageio/imageio/issues/329). It works for me on Linux.

Comment: Furas, I actually read this post whilst I was investigating a previous challenge.

I see this code here:-
https://github.com/imageio/imageio/blob/master/imageio/plugins/freeimage.py

however it is not clear to me how to read an image file using freeimage.py, Do you know how to do this ?

Comment: you don't have to use `freeimage.py`. You have to install [freeimage.dll](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/download.html) in system (I assume you use Windows) and use `format='PNG-FI'` in `imageio.imread`/`imageio.imwrite` - like in example in link.

Comment: in plugin code I see you can install DLL using python code `imageio.plugins.freeimage.download()`. OR in command line `imageio_download_bin freeimage`

Comment: in last code you have too much variables so finally you write original image instead of resized one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `imageio` with `freeimage` library using `format='PNG-FI'` in `imageio.imread` / `imageoio.imwrite`.

Based on information in source code of [freeimage.py](https://github.com/imageio/imageio/blob/master/imageio/plugins/freeimage.py) in `imageio` to install `freeimage` library you can use `imageio`:

- in command line (on Linux it works even without full path)

  ```
  imageio_download_bin freeimage
  ```
- using python code

  ```
  import imageio

  imageio.plugins.freeimage.download()
  ```

Probably if you install library (`.dll`/`.so`) directly from [FreeImage webpage](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/download.html) then it will also work.

---

Image has to be copied (`img.copy()`). Because making image smaller it removed pixels with the biggest values so I work with part of image and make its bigger.

```
# read 48bit color
img = imageio.imread("..\\..\\000000_10.png", format='PNG-FI')

# max values in image
print('shape:', img.shape)
print('max R:', img[:,:,0].max())
print('max G:', img[:,:,1].max())
print('max B:', img[:,:,2].max())
print('---')

# cut-off part of image (with)
img = img.copy()
img = img[370:375,1020:1025,:]
img = img.copy()
img.resize((256,256,3))

print('shape:', img.shape)
print('max R:', img[:,:,0].max())
print('max G:', img[:,:,1].max())
print('max B:', img[:,:,2].max())
print('---')

# find X,Y for first max red value
print('max X:', img[:,:,0].max(axis=0).argmax())
print('max Y:', img[:,:,0].max(axis=1).argmax())
print(' flat:', img[:,:,0].argmax())
print('---')

# find X,Y for all max red values
max_r = img[:,:,0].max()

for y, row in enumerate(img[:,:,0]):
    for x, it in enumerate(row):
        if it == max_r:
            print('value/x/y:', max_r, x, y)

# write 48bit color
imageio.imwrite('output_48bit.png', img, format='PNG-FI')
```

Output:

```
shape: (375, 1242, 3)
max R: 40827
max G: 36674
max B: 1
---
shape: (256, 256, 3)
max R: 40827
max G: 36506
max B: 1
---
max X: 14
max Y: 0
 flat: 14
---
value/x/y: 40827 14 0
```

---

In Linux I can use program `file in command line to check if file use 48bit color (16bits per color)

```
$ file 000000_10.png

000000_10.png: PNG image data, 1242 x 375, 16-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced


$ file output_48bit.png 

output_48bit.png: PNG image data, 256 x 256, 16-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced
```

---

If you have `RGBA` then it will use 64bit color.

Example from `imageio` issues: [Unable to properly read multi-channel 16-bit png files](https://github.com/imageio/imageio/issues/329)

```
import imageio
import numpy as np

img_out = np.zeros((256, 256, 4), dtype=np.uint16)
color_grad = np.reshape(np.arange(2**16), (256,-1))
img_out[:, :, 0] = color_grad
img_out[:, :, 1] = np.rot90(color_grad, 1)
img_out[:, :, 2] = np.rot90(color_grad, 2)
img_out[:, :, 3] = np.rot90(color_grad, 3)

print('Write unique values: R={}, G={}, B={}, A={}'.format(
    len(set(img_out[:, :, 0].flatten().tolist())),
    len(set(img_out[:, :, 1].flatten().tolist())),
    len(set(img_out[:, :, 2].flatten().tolist())),
    len(set(img_out[:, :, 3].flatten().tolist()))))
imageio.imwrite('64bit_imageio.png', img_out, format='PNG-FI')

img_in_imageio = imageio.imread('64bit_imageio.png', format='PNG-FI')
print('imageio PNG unique values: R={}, G={}, B={}, A={}'.format(
    len(set(img_in_imageio[:, :, 0].flatten().tolist())),
    len(set(img_in_imageio[:, :, 1].flatten().tolist())),
    len(set(img_in_imageio[:, :, 2].flatten().tolist())),
    len(set(img_in_imageio[:, :, 3].flatten().tolist()))))
```

Output:

```
Write unique values: R=65536, G=65536, B=65536, A=65536
imageio PNG unique values: R=65536, G=65536, B=65536, A=65536

output_48bit.png: PNG image data, 5 x 5, 16-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced
```

---

**EDIT:** Your last code with more readable names for variables (lower_case_names) and few free lines to make it also more readable.

In original code you had mess so finally you wrote original image instead of resized one.

```
import cv2
import imageio

# need it only once 
#imageio.plugins.freeimage.download()

input_filename  = "..\\..\\000000_10.png"
output_filename = "..\\..\\000000_10_resized.png"

input_image  = imageio.imread(input_filename, format='PNG-FI')
output_image = cv2.resize(input_image, (256, 256))

imageio.imwrite(output_filename, output_image, format='PNG-FI')
```

Comment: @CogT in the future, you can put code inside backticks ( ` ), which will make `code`.  Comments don't support newlines, but that'll still make it easier to read.

Comment: So I think I need to use the OpenCV resize method, but it doesn't seem to work, you can see my attempts above.

Comment: in first example I used your image and it keeps 48bits. Second example is only for those how don't want to download file but still want to test it. The only problem I saw is because it changes size from bigger to smaller so it has to remove some pixels and less frequent pixels disappear - and `max()` gives smaller values. But image is still 48bit.

Comment: I checked both new code in question and both works for me on Linux. Both give me `16bit/color`. But in second code you write original image instead of resized.  If you have error then you should add full Traceback, not only last line. There are other important information.

Comment: @Furas, thanks Furas.  I added the full traceback above.  I need to use openCV for the resize, but it's now working.  Any suggestions ?  I use windows.

Comment: why do you have to use resize from OpenCV ? Second version works correctly if you use correct variable in `imwrite` - `Resized_Image` instead of `img_in_imageio`. You wrote original image instead of resized one.

Comment: char `_` at the beginning of function's name `_open()` means it is private function and other peole shouldn't use it. Of couse you can use it if you know how it works. But this function wasn't created to use it directly and it doesn't work as you expect. It seems it doesn't need file name but something different. But you may not find documentation for this function and it may need much more work to use it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your imput Furas, my code now works.
To explain.  I resized the KITTI test images to 256 x 256 using openCV.  When these are forward passed through the CNN they generate KITTI Flow format sized to 256 x 256, However actual Kitti groundtruth flow is larger.  So instead of retraining my network with larger frames, I decided to resize the KITTI Ground Truth flow, to see if I can get an indicative evaluation with limited compute.  Speed up parametric research evaluation.
I also thought this could lead to a faster parametric research approach in the model development stages.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Resize 48bit PNG file and maintain 48bit PNG when saving to file WORKING

import cv2
import imageio
imageio.plugins.freeimage.download()
PNG_Location_Filepath = "..\\..\\000000_10.png"
Resized_Location_Filepath = "..\\..\\000000_10_resized.png"
img_in_imageio = imageio.imread(PNG_Location_Filepath, format='PNG-FI')
Resized_Image = cv2.resize(img_in_imageio, (256,256))
Saved_Filename = Resized_Location_Filepath
imageio.imwrite(Saved_Filename, Resized_Image, format='PNG-FI')

#This works to resize the image, keeping 48bits
```